# How to allow public access to a specific file inside a restricted <Location> statement in Apache 2.4

Tags: apache, httpd.conf

Is it possible to allow access to a specific file in a path that is otherwise denied with a Location statment? I have tried the below in httpd.conf, but seems the Files statment has no effect and I cannot access the specific file from a public IP (other than 123.123). If this configuration is not possible, is there an alternative way to setup this restriction? I prefer Location to Directory, as Location will affect all sites on the server.

```
<Location /wp-admin>
        SetEnvIF X-Forwarded-For "123.123" AllowIP
        Require env AllowIP
        Require ip 123.123
</Location>

<Files admin-ajax.php>
        Require all granted
</Files>
```